# attr_accessor or custom methods duplicate method names confusion

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I do understand that Ruby supports short-hand style of calling methods i.e: `1.+(2)` is same as `1+2` (and I still think if it related to my situation), but I got really confused why `attr_accessor` methods are neither duplicate (well, they should not be, as `writer` differs with `=` in its name) nor they differ with anything (except `writer` needs an argument) while accessing them outside active object.

My question is included in this code (in the second comment)

```
class Test
  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end
  def number
    @number
  end
  def number=(n)
    @number = n
  end
end

t = Test.new(12)

puts t.number # => 12
t.number = 13 # Why does it do what t.number=(13) should do
puts t.number # => 13
```

I wonder why `t.number = 13` works, when it points to a method which should only return a number and moreover how does it set a new value when `t.number=(13)` is not called instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.number = 13` is just a shorthand for `t.number=(13)`, they are effectively the same statement in Ruby.

`attr_accessor :b` creates the equivalent of the following two methods:

```
def b
  @b
end
def b=(new_val)
  @b = new_val
end
```

So in your code example, you could replace the two methods `#number` and `#number=` with `attr_accessor :number`

Comment: thanks, but why does this code not work then? `def show=(str)
  puts str
end

show = "confused"`

Comment: Ruby interprets the statement `show = "confused"` as setting a local variable, and not a method call, becuase there is no object + period (`.`) before `show`. If you had said `object.show = "confused"`, it interprets it as a method call, but without `object.` its just setting a local variable

Comment: okay but `show=("confused")` works neither, please tell me this too

Comment: I see, so the same thing is with my `show=("confused")` because `p show` would respond with `"confused"`. Big thanks @Stuart M